# How to return dataframes specific columns using strings and list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a dataframe testDF with columns C1:C6 and a list:

```
List = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
```

and I want to select these columns plus more.

So, I tried:

```
test1 = testDF.loc[(testDF.C1 == blah) & (testDF.C2== blah)]['C5', 'C6', List]]
```

With returned:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I know it's possible to:

```
test1 = testDF.loc[(testDF.C1 == blah) & (testDF.C2== blah)][List]
```

But, I like to think its possible to combine list and strings to specify columns.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

testDF = pd.DataFrame([['something', 'very likely', 3, 4, 5, 6],['something else', 'likely', 9, 10, 11, 12],['not here', 'possible', 15, 16]], columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6'])
```

Yields:

```
               C1           C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
0       something  very likely   3   4   5   6
1  something else       likely   9  10  11  12
2        not here     possible  15  16  17  18
```

Then:

```
List = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']

test1 = testDF.loc[(testDF.C1.str.contains('something')) & (testDF.C2.str.contains('likely'))][List]
```

Yields:

```
               C1           C2  C3  C4
0       something  very likely   3   4
1  something else       likely   9  10
```

If you would like the columns that match (not just contains), then you can use `str.match` w/ a regex, like so:

```
test1 = testDF.loc[(testDF.C1.str.match(r'^something$')) & (testDF.C2.str.match(r'.*?likely'))][List]
```

Yields:

```
          C1           C2  C3  C4
0  something  very likely   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
test1 = testDF.loc[(testDF.C1 == blah) & (testDF.C2== blah)][['C5']+['C6']+List]]
```